# Overloading operator new

Tags: c++

I am overloading operator new as below

```
class A {
public:
    void* operator new(size_t) { return (void*) Buf; }
};
```

I am getting "declaration of operator new as non-function error" when I try to compile. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have any macros which define 'new' to something else for debugging? Those macros might be mangling up the operator declaration here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you `size_t` be defined? You need to include `stddef.h` for it. But better you include `cstddef` and use `std::size_t`.

Your declaration otherwise looks fine, apart from the semantics of always returning `Buf` being screwed up. The `operator new` should return a buffer of the size specified as the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are using a fairly modern and strict compiler. The error you are getting is because `size_t` is not recognized. Strictly you need to `#include` something that defines it and you should also use the C++ name: `std::size_t`.

E.g.

```
#include <cstddef>

class A{
public:
void* operator new(std::size_t) { return (void*) Buf;}
};
```